# How to determine if a specific module is loaded in linux kernel

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, insmod

I am just curious is there any way to determine if a particular module is loaded/installed.

$ lsmod lists all modules (device driver loaded).

Is there any way to check or a command that returns true/false boolean output if a module name is polled. For eg. if keyboard.o exists return true else false. I need this tip to complete my driver auto refresh program.

PS: tried modinfo. I am using busybox client in my test DUT so can you give some alternatives other than modinfo?

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous. Are you trying to check if the driver is loaded into memory or installed on the system? modinfo would help with the latter but not the former.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

not sure if `modinfo modname` and checking `$?` will work for you, just a suggestion.

```
/tmp$ sudo modinfo e1000
/tmp$ echo $?
0
/tmp$ sudo modinfo keyboard
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module keyboard
/tmp$ echo $?
1
```

alternatively you also grep `/proc/modules`

Comment: Just a note: the `modinfo` approach doesn't seem to actually work for the _loaded_ check (as in the question title). It shows info regardless of whether the module is loaded.

Comment: This is not a good solution. modinfo shows information of a kernel module installed on the rootfs, but it doesn't check  if the module is loaded into the kernel or not. So this solution should not be used to solve the issue.

Comment: Only `lsmod` and `/proc/modules` show what modules are **loaded**.

Answer (score 45):

The `modinfo module` method does not work well for me. I prefer this method that is similar to the alternative method proposed:

```
#!/bin/sh

MODULE="$1"

if lsmod | grep -wq "$MODULE"; then
  echo "$MODULE is loaded!"
  exit 0
else
  echo "$MODULE is not loaded!"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `grep -Eq "^${MODULE} ";`

Comment: `grep -wq "^${MODULE}"` to catch the word

Answer (score 18):

The `--first-time` flag causes `modprobe` to fail if the module is already loaded. That in conjunction with the `--dry-run` (or the shorthand `-n`) flag makes a nice test:

```
modprobe -n --first-time $MODULE && echo "Not loaded" || echo "Loaded"
```

**Edit 1:** As @Nobody pointed out this also prints `Loaded` if the module does not exist. We can fix this by combining it with `modinfo`:

```
modinfo $MODULE >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &&
! modprobe -n --first-time $MODULE 2>/dev/null &&
echo "Loaded" || echo "Not loaded"
```

**Edit 2:** On some systems `modprobe` lives in `/usr/sbin`, which is not in the `$PATH` unless you are root. In that case you have to substitute `modprobe` for `/usr/sbin/modprobe` in the above.

Comment: Problem: Needs root and when you enter bullshit for $MODULE it claims that $MODULE is loaded.

Comment: @Nobody It does not require root on my system.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was only half-right (or maybe quarter-right. Shame on you comment-up-voters). On Debian, modprobe is not in $PATH for normal users, so just copy&pasting your command only works as root. But when calling modprobe with its full path, it's executable for normal users and only the actual inserting operation fails, so your solution works in principle. I still think querying /proc/modules is more elegant, but that's a matter of taste. Had I downvoted your answer, I would have removed the vote now (but I didn't).

Answer (score 9):

I wrote this:

```
MODULE=snd_aloop # for example
test -n "$(grep -e "^$MODULE " /proc/modules)" && echo "Loaded" || echo "Not loaded"
```

It checks in `/proc/modules`. If the module is mentioned there, it's assumed to be loaded, otherwise not.

The others seemed too long to me (the other short one requires root, this does not). Of course it's just written out what was already mentioned as "alternatives".

Caution: `modprobe` accepts some variants of module names other than the primary listed in `/proc/modules`. For example loading `snd-aloop` works, but the module is named `snd_aloop` and is listed as such in `/proc/modules` and when using `rmmod` that's also the only name that will work.

Comment: You may want to match for `"^$MODULE\>"` instead to make sure you aren't matching just part of the module name.

Answer (score 9):

My short way to find if a given module is actually loaded:

```
cat /proc/modules | grep -c nfnetlink
```

which outputs

```
2
```

That `2` (TWO) means the module is LOADED. The actual output without `-c` shows all loaded modules with MODULENAME - `-c` counts the lines that contain MODULENAME. So if you have `0` (ZERO) lines as output then the module is not loaded

Comment: You can use it with if. `if cat /proc/modules | grep -c nfnetlink; then echo "module loaded" fi`

Answer (score 7):

The better idea is to create a bash function:

```
#!/bin/sh
function moduleExist(){
  MODULE="$1"
  if lsmod | grep "$MODULE" &> /dev/null ; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}


if moduleExist "module name"; then
  #do somthing
fi
```

Comment: What difference is there from @basfest's answer?

Comment: Dear @JonathanLam, I try to convert the code into a simple function and reuse it in my sell script. As you can see the condition expression is readable.

Answer (score 2):

```
 !/bin/sh
 # Module
 MODULE="scsi_dh_rdac"

 #Variables check if module loaded or not
 MODEXIST=/sbin/lsmod | grep "$MODULE"

 if [ -z "$MODEXIST" ]; then
       /sbin/modprobe "$MODULE" >/dev/null 2>&1
 fi
```

Comment: Although your answer looks good, you should include a little explanation... plain code may be good, but code *and* explanation is better

Answer (score 0):

```
module list
```

Returns:

```
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
  1) /coverm/0.3.0        2) /parallel/20180222
```

Comment: Where did you get `module` from...?

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -wEq "^${module%.o}" /proc/modules
```

returns true (e.g. can be used in an if) whether you ask for `keyboard` or `keyboard.o`

Answer (score 0):

`grep -q $pattern` against `lsmod` or `/proc/modules`, which are available on most systems and a standard "source of truth"

```
lsmod | grep -q $pattern
```

```sh
$ lsmod | grep -q msr
$ echo $?
0
```

```sh
$ lsmod | grep -q duediligencemuch
$ echo $?
1
```